# SFTP source port used by client

Tags: ssh, port, sftp

What port is used by a client when connecting to `SFTP` server listening on port `22`?
In which range can be that port? Does that range depend on client application used, or it depends on operating system?

```
CLIENT_APP:CLIENT_PORT ----------------> SERVER:22

CLIENT_APP:CLIENT_PORT <---------------- SERVER:22
```

Comment: Source port is usually a random number > 1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Linux system, the default source port range can be found by running

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

but in general the source port will be in the range 32768-65535.